# Code is not linked with math.h even though -lm is in add_compile_options

Tags: c, cmake

I've got some C code which is compiled with help of CMake (in CLion):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct ball {
    double x, y, z, r;
} ball;

bool intersect(ball *a, ball *b) {
    double d = sqrt(pow(a->x - b->x, 2) + pow(a->y - b->y, 2) + pow(a->z - b->z, 2));
    return d <= a->r + b->r;
}
```

I've also got my CMakeLists, which specify `-lm` as compiler option. It is also the last option:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(untitled C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

add_compile_options(-Wall -Werror -Wformat-security -Wignored-qualifiers -Winit-self -Wswitch-default -Wfloat-equal -Wpointer-arith -Wtype-limits -Wempty-body -Wno-logical-op -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-declaration -Wold-style-definition -Wmissing-parameter-type -Wmissing-field-initializers -Wnested-externs -Wno-pointer-sign -Wno-unused-result -std=gnu99 -lm)

add_executable(untitled main.c)
```

However, when compiling, I get a bunch of undefined references:

```
Scanning dependencies of target untitled
[ 50%] Building C object CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/main.c.o
[100%] Linking C executable untitled
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/main.c.o: in function `intersect':
/home/keddad/CLionProjects/untitled/main.c:10: undefined reference to `pow'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/keddad/CLionProjects/untitled/main.c:10: undefined reference to `pow'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/keddad/CLionProjects/untitled/main.c:10: undefined reference to `pow'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/keddad/CLionProjects/untitled/main.c:10: undefined reference to `sqrt'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/build.make:93: untitled] Error 1
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/all] Error 2
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:90: CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/rule] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:124: untitled] Error 2
```

What am I doing wrong? I've read another questions on the topic, and I thought that as long as I had `-lm`, and it is specified as a last compiler argument, it should work fine. However, looks like it's not the case here.

Answer (score 2):

The [`add_compile_options`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_compile_options.html) is to add *compiler* flags, not linker flags or libraries.

To link with a library use the [`target_link_libraries`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) command:

```
add_executable(untitled main.c)
target_link_libraries(untitled m)
```

---

On another note, prefer [`target_compile_options`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_options.html) instead of `add_compile_options`.

Comment: Thanks! I thought it just passes all those arguments to GCC as-is

Comment: @keddad Building is done in two steps: Compilation into object files, and linking object files with libraries.